# IQR, Quartiles and n in table1 function

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a table for descriptive statistics for different variables (continuous, categorical) stratified by a group. As example dataset I use the "lung" dataset from the survival package:

```
library(survival)
library(table1)

mydata = survival::lung

mydata$sex <- as.factor(mydata$sex)

t1 <- table1(~ age + ph.ecog + ph.karno | sex, data = mydata, overall = FALSE)
t1
```

For continuous variables I would like to get the following characteristics:

- min, max
- 25 percent quartile median (SD) 75 percent quartile
  interquartile range
- n per group and variable (i.e. number included for the analysis). The missing values are reported by default - I would like to report
  the number of rows available (i.e. number of rows per group (on the
  top of the columns) minus missing values (this is not very important)

Currently the min, max are reported in [] after the median.

Is it possible to customize this table1 function? I was not able to find a hint in the documentation...

Thank you!

Comment: Yes it is. Look at this Vignettes under SUBTITLE: "Using abbreviated code to specify a custom renderer" & "Displaying different statistics for different variables" on the webpage: https://benjaminrich.github.io/table1/vignettes/table1-examples.html

Comment: Great, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Bloxx I found the solution here:

https://benjaminrich.github.io/table1/vignettes/table1-examples.html#using-abbreviated-code-to-specify-a-custom-renderer

The parameter is "render.continuous" in the tablet1 function.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
render.NEW <- function(x, name, data2, ...) {
    MIN <- min(x, na.rm = T)
    MAX <- max(x, na.rm = T)
    median <- median(x, na.rm = T)
    Q1 <- quantile(x, 0.25, na.rm = T)
    Q3 <- quantile(x, 0.75, na.rm = T)
    N = length(x) - sum(is.na(x))
    
    out <- c("",
             "[min, max]" = paste0("[", sprintf("%.2f", MIN), ", ", sprintf("%.2f", MAX), "]"),
             "Median [Q1, Q3]" = paste0(sprintf("%.2f", median), " [", sprintf("%.2f", Q1), ", ", sprintf("%.2f", Q3), "]"),
             "N" = N)
    out
}

table1(~ age + ph.ecog + ph.karno | sex, data = mydata, overall = FALSE, 
   render = render.NEW)
```